# Iterating through a list and comparing to a csv file - python

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, for-loop

I have a CSV file that is comprised of three columns: Partners, Places and Values.

There are duplicates in the column Partners so I sorted this data into a list of unique partner names: list(UNIQ)

I want to find the total value for each partner. I.e. take bob from the list of unique partners, and then go into the csv file and find all the values associated with bob and add them together.

Then take the name Bob and the total value and append it to a dictionary.

Repeat this process for all names in the list.

so far my code is this:

```
PVAL = {'partner':0, 'value':0}

with open('/Users/tb/Desktop/data.csv', 'r') as f:
   EXP = csv.reader(f)
   for j in range(len(list(UNIQ))):
       P1 = list(UNIQ)[j]
       for row in EXP:
           if row[0] == P1:
              PVAL.update({'partner': row[0], 'value': row[2]})
print PVAL
```

this returns: {'partner': '1551e96b8234', 'value': '0.00541867434354'}

0.00541867434354 is just one of many values for for partner '1551e96b8234'.

I know I need to use the sum function but I can't crack it. 
In english the code should read " for all instances of bob in the csv file, sum up all the associated values and add them to the dictionary with bobs name."

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide sample CSV file?

Comment: each column contains thousands of data points.  Partners and Places are written like: algkjlg8slkg099 I.e. a mixture of numbers and letters. and the values are floats like 0.004626

Comment: Sounds like it would be really easy to provide a half-dozen lined example csv. Consider that the people answering questions prefer to test them. That means that they have to generate the file. Its easier for everyone if the example is in the question to reduce the work we need to do and for a better comparison of answers.

Comment: It doesn't matter at this point because you already have a good answer, but a good question should be easy to test!

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip, I'm fairly new here :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want. Just build up a dictionary mapping the partner to the sum of the associated values:

```
from collections import defaultdict
totals = defaultdict(float)

with open('/Users/tb/Desktop/data.csv', 'r') as f:
   EXP = csv.reader(f)
   for row in EXP:
       totals[row[0]] += float(row[2])
print totals
```

If there is a header row you can skip it with `next(EXP)` just before the `for` loop.

```
from collections import defaultdict
totals = defaultdict(float)

with open('/Users/tb/Desktop/data.csv', 'r') as f:
   EXP = csv.reader(f)
   headers = next(EXP)
   for row in EXP:
       totals[row[0]] += float(row[2])
print totals
```

Comment: This gives me : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tb/Desktop/title.py", line 35, in <module>
    TOTALS[row[0]] += float(row[2])

Comment: It would help if you included the error message from the traceback, but most likely at least on of your 'values' column isn't a number.

Comment: Updated the answer to skip a header row.

Comment: I think the error is in this line: TOTALS[row[0]] += float([2]) .                     row[0] is the column containing all the names like bob, linda etc and row[2] gives the values... I want to add all values from row 2 that correspond to Bob ... Sorry to bother you, i'm a beginner :(

Comment: But what sort of error is it? `ValueError`, `IndexError`, or something else?

Comment: oh woah i got something :O :O Thanks a bunch Duncan! So happy :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a straight dictionary, use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which will do the adding for you automatically when you call `.update()`:

```
from collections import Counter
PVAL = Counter()

PVAL.update({'partner': 1})
PVAL.update({'partner': 2.5})

# PVAL is now {'partner': 3.5}
```